# How to find jump discontinuities with integers and less than or equal sign?

Tags: calculus

f(x) = [x]  = the greatest integer <= x.

The book says there's a jump discontinuity at every integer. How is that determined?

Another problem says "x-[x]," and the answer is "nonremovable discontinuity at every integer."

Why is there a discrepancy between the answers to the two problems? Shouldn't those be the same answer, either jumps or nonremovables?

Comment: $f(x)$ has a removable discontinuity if for some $x_0$ we have $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)\ne f(x_0)$, so we can simply redefine $f(x_0)$ as the limit. $f(x)$ has a jump discontinuity at $x_0$ if $\lim_{x\to x_0^-}f(x)\ne \lim_{x\to x_0^+}f(x)$. So a jump discontinuity is never removable.

Comment: I don't understand what that means. How can I determine that the first problem is a jump while the second is not?

Comment: Both $[x]$ and $x-[x]$ have discontinuities which can be described both as "jump" discontinuities or as "non-removable" discontinuities.